# Need to generate files based on the value available in a variable in shell

Tags: shell, unix, ksh

In my script I have a variable `$var` which will hold a value "00135 00136 00137". I want to generate three files based on the values available in `$var` - if possible without using a loop.

For example, I need touch files with these names:

```
test.00136.txt
test.00137.txt
test.00138.txt
```

Comment: Don't be afraid for a loop when it helps you: `echo "$var" | while read var1 var2 var3; do ` is simple. Faster is using parameter expansion, but that is a little harder to read.

Comment: here the variable is not a static value $var may have values like "000135 00136 00137 00138 00139"  so how to read all these respectively

Comment: Again a loop: `for mynumber in $var; do touch test.${mynumber}.txt; done`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Avioding a while loop is possible with xargs.
First split the var into lines, use the string num as a placeholder and touch the files:

```
var="000135 00136 00137 00138 00139"
echo "${var}" | tr " " "\n" | xargs -I num touch test.num.txt
```

Edit:
Avoid tr with

```
echo -n "$var" | xargs -d' '  -n1  -Inum echo test.num.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

The `awk` utility makes processing columnar data quite simple:

```
var="00135 00136 00137"

var1=$(echo "$var" | awk '{print $1}')
var2=$(echo "$var" | awk '{print $2}')
var3=$(echo "$var" | awk '{print $3}')

touch "test.${var1}.txt"
touch "test.${var2}.txt"
touch "test.${var3}.txt"
```

Comment: here the variable is not a static value $var may have values like "000135 00136 00137 00138 00139" so how to read all these vaues respectively